# MongoDB date range query not working in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have dates in mongoDB stored as ISODate objects that looks like this

```
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2018-01-20T11:39:22Z") }
```

I have a date range query in MongoDB the works perfectly and returns 1152 records using this query:

```
db.tweets.find({ 'created_at': {$gte: new Date("2018-01-20T00:00:00Z"), $lt: new Date("2018-01-25T00:00:00Z")}})
```

However, when transforming it into PHP query, I get an error like this:

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

Here is my PHP query:

```
$document = $collection->find([ 'created_at'=> ['$gte'=> new mongoDate("2018-01-20T00:00:00Z"), '$lt'=> new mongoDate("2018-01-25T00:00:00Z")]]);
```

By the way im using the "php_mongodb-1.3.4-5.6-ts-vc11", the latest stable mongoDB PHP driver.